# Big O - Why is this algorithm O(AxB)?

Tags: loops, big-o

I am unsure why this code evaluates to O(A*B)?

```
void printUnorderedPairs(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) { 
  for (int i= 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
      for (int k=  0; k < 100000; k++) {
        System.out.println(arrayA[i] + "," + arrayB[j]); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sure, more precisely its O(1000*A*B) and we would drop the 1000 making it O(A*B). But what if array A had a length of 2? wouldn't the 1000 iterations be more significant? Is it just because we know the final loop is constant (and its value is shown) that we don't count it? what if we knew all of the arrays sizes?

Can anyone explain why we would not say its O(A*B*C)? What would be the runtime if I made the code this:

```
int[] arrayA = new int[20];
int[] arrayB = new int[500];
int[] arrayC = new int[100000];

void printUnorderedPairs(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) { 
  for (int i= 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
      for (int k=  0; k < arrayC.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(arrayA[i] + "," + arrayB[j]); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the running time (or number of execution steps, or number of times `println` gets called, or whatever you are assessing with your Big O notation) is O(AB), it means that the running time approaches being *linearly proportional to* AB **as AB grows without bound** (approaches infinity).  It is literally a limit to infinity, in terms of calculus.

Big O is not concerned with what happens for any finite number of iterations.  It's about what the limiting behaviour of the function is as its free variables approach infinity.  Sure, for small values of A there could very well be a constant term that dominates execution time.  But as A approaches infinity, all those other factors becomes insignificant.

Consider a polynomial like `Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cn + D`.  It  will be proportional to `x^3` as x grows to infinity - regardless of the magnitude of A, B, C, or D.  B can be Grahams number for all Big O cares; infinity is still way bigger than any big finite number you pick and therefore the x^3 term dominates.

So first, considering *what if A were 2* is not really in the spirit of *AB approaching infinity*.  [Any number you can fit on a whiteboard basically rounds down to zero.](https://what-if.xkcd.com/151/).

And second, remember that *proportional to AB* means equal to AB times some constant; and it doesn't matter what that constant is.  It is fine if the constant happens to be 10000.  Saying something is proportional to 2N is the same as saying it is proportional to N, or any other number times N.  So O(2N) is the same as O(N).  By convention we always simplify when using Big-O notation to drop any constant factors.  So we would always write O(N), and never O(2N).  And for that same reason, we would write O(AB) and not O(10000AB).

And finally we don't say O(ABC) only because "C" (the number of iterations of your inner loop in your question) happens to be a constant; which also happens to equal 10000.  That's why we say it's O(AB) and not O(ABC) because C is not a free variable; it's hard-coded to 10000.  If the size of B were not expected to change (were to be constant for whatever reason) then you could say that it is simply O(A).  But if you allow B to grow without bound, then the limit is O(AB) and if you also allow C to grow without bound then the limit is O(ABC).  You get to decide which numbers are constant and which variables are free variables depending on the context of your analysis.

You can read more about [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) at Wikipedia.

Comment: Detailed answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate that the `for` loops in `i` and `j` are independent of each other, so their running time is `O(A*B)`.  The inner loop in `k` is a fixed number of iterations, 100000, and also is independent of the two outer loops, so we get `O(100000*A*B)`.  But, since the `k` loop is just a constant (non variable) penalty, with are still left with `O(A*B)` for the overall complexity.

If you were to write the inner loop in `k` from 0 to `C`, then you could write `O(A*B*C)` for the complexity, and that would be valid as well.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the `A*B` doesn't matter, and it's just considered `O(N)`.

If there was some knowledge that `A` and `B` were *always* somewhat the same length, then one could argue that it's really `O(N^2)`.

Any sort of constant doesn't really matter in order-notation, because for really really large numbers of `A`/`B`, the constant becomes of negligible importance.

Answer (score 1):

```
void printUnorderedPairs(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) { 
  for (int i= 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
      for (int k=  0; k < 100000; k++) {
        System.out.println(arrayA[i] + "," + arrayB[j]); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code is evaluated to O(A*B), because arrayC has constant length. Of course, its run time is proportional to A*B*100000. Here, we never care about constant values, because when the variables get higher and higher like 10^10000, the constants can be easily ignored.

In the second code, we say its O(1), because all arrays have constant length and we can calculate its run time without any variable.